# How to use MS Team Build with other compilers?

Tags: embedded, tfsbuild, build-automation, firmware

I've been using Team Build 2010 successfully to automate builds where the source code is written in MS C#/C++.

Now I have to automate firmware code that is compiled with a compiler from TI. The TI project has a .pjt extension and I do have the tools (make like) to compile from a command prompt.

Do I have to create a MSBuild project for that?

Comment: I got it working by creating a simple MSBuild project with a couple of "Exec" commands calling my version of "make". It's working, but I don't know if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Does the .pjt file have the same format as any other MSBuild project files like .csproj?

Comment: Not at all. It resembles the old .ini architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a "makefile project" in Visual Studio,  you can then set-up a custom build command (it does not need to be a makefile).  You the use then use the TI command line build tool *timake* to build the project defined in the .pjt file.  This will create a VC++ project file that builds the .pjt file.  I am not that familiar with MSBuild, but it can also probably run *timake* directly.

If you want to use Visual Studio for development and benefit from its Intellisense features, you will also need to add the include paths list for the project to the VS project, and also any command line macros defined.

Comment: MSbuild is the solution indeed. Just create a .proj file with a MSBuild target and invoke the timake with a MSBuild Exec task.